# Почему строка не сохраняет значение?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, строки

Пытаюсь сделать свое поле набора номера телефона. Вроде, все правильно, но когда я манипулирую со строкой. Её значение почему-то не изменяется. В чём проблема? Может из-за локальной области видимости? Не знаю.

```js
var
  phone = "+7(___)___-__-__",
  currentID = 3,
  input = jQuery('input[name="feedback__phone"]');


input.keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 8) { //Если нажат backspace
    phone[currentID] = "_";
    if (currentID == 7 || currentID == 11 || currentID == 14) {
      currentID -= 2;
    } else if (currentID > 3) {
      currentID--;
    }
  } else if (e.keyCode < 58 && e.keyCode > 47) { //Если нажаты цифры
    phone[currentID] = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);

    if (currentID == 5 || currentID == 9 || currentID == 12) {
      currentID += 2;
    } else if (currentID != 15) {
      currentID++;
    }
  }

  input.val(phone);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="feedback__phone" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Строки в js *неизменяемые* - это означает, что **нельзя** присвоить отдельный символ строки.

Одно из решений, например:

1. сделать из строки массив: `var phoneArr = phone.split('')`
2. заменить Нужный символ: `phoneArr[currentID] = char`
3. объединить массив, и переписать начальную переменную: `phone = phoneArr.join('')`

Первый шаг можно опустить, если хранить в `phone` - сразу массив и приводить его к строке в момент передачи в `input.val(...)`